# Does Camel manipulate the content of a 'done' file?

Tags: apache-camel

Generally "done" file or trigger file is a blank file. Because it indicates the end of a process. My requirement is to process the records of a file only after checking the number of records in the file exactly matches with the number, mentioned in the "done" file.

In this case the "done" file would not be blank. It would contain a number. Would camel router allow to manipulate the content of a "done" file?

Answer (score 0):

No, out of the box **you cannot write done files with a content**. They are always empty.

This is also stated in the [documentation of the file component](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/file-component.html) (in the description of the `doneFilename` option):

> The done file will be empty.